Uploaded image from script to Figma file through API on Python doesn't appear
I'm trying to upload several images from my pc to figma file. The script sees the file, its nodes and ids, but can't put the image inside file, despite no errors. I've created a server through python -m http.server 8000, and uploading from there.
If anyone has ideas how to fix this, please, write or ask details.
Here's code:
import requests
import os
import traceback

# Personal Figma token
TOKEN = "token"
FILE_KEY = "file key"

# Auth
HEADERS = {
    "X-Figma-Token": TOKEN
}

# Uploading to Figma
def upload_image_to_node(node_id, image_url):
    url = f"https://api.figma.com/v1/images/{FILE_KEY}"
    json_data = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "node_id": node_id,
                "fill": {
                    "type": "IMAGE",
                    "image_url": image_url,
                    "scale_mod": "FILL"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=HEADERS, json=json_data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f"Image {image_url} successfully uploaded to node {node_id}.")
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

# Main
def process_images(input_folder, node_id):
    base_url = "http://localhost:8000"
    for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
        if filename.endswith((".png", ".jpg")):
            image_url = f"{base_url}/{filename}"
            upload_image_to_node(node_id, image_url)

try:
    node_id = "0:1" # Main node in Figma
    process_images("out/", node_id) # out/ is where images stored
except Exception as e:
    print("Error occured:")
    traceback.print_exc()
    input("Press Enter to quit..")



This is not possible with Figma's REST API. There are no endpoints that allow this. Also note that the endpoint you are using only supports the GET method. Please refer to the developer documentation: https://www.figma.com/developers/api#get-images-endpoint
